# .net 4.0 appears not to be installed in the server manager > application server on win2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

on the 64 bit win 2008 server, .net 4.0 is not mentioned in the role services - just the 3.5.1 .net framework. Could this be why my MVC programs arent working on IIS 7.5 with the 404 /403 messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server 2008 was released a long time before .NET 4, the core OS knows nothing of .NET 4 unless you explicitly install it. And it will still not be listed in Server Manager | Features.

Server 2008 will just list 3.0 (the current version of .NET when it was released, Server 2008 *R2* lists 3.5.1 (as you mention IIS7.5 it seems you are actually using Server 2008 R2).

Once .NET 4 is installed you can create (or use) one of the .NET 4 application pools for your application.